# ASP.NET gives me a hard time

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a serious problem. I created a asp.net website and created a web form and the code behind for that page was an `aspx.cs` file. Which is correct. But now when I try to add a new form, it creates an `aspx.vb` code behind.

How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that inside the same application? Or did you just happen to create a new application and picked `VB` as its language??

Comment: Same application. I already have an aspx.cs code behind for ins web form. But all of the sudden it starts with the aspx.vb... and I dont know why.

Comment: VS 2012. let me try to add a screenshot? this is weird... really weird.

Comment: I have edited my post and uploaded a picture.

Comment: Its still a vb one. I started off with C# as I always do. I don't like VB.NET at all.

Comment: That's what I say too. whis is weird. and this is a very large website already, I'm just maintaining. So just starting over would take very long

Comment: Ok I'll see what I can do. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I right-click on a folder and say: Add New --> Web Form. Its automatically switching to VB.NET as the Code-Behind.

Comment: Sure - but can you show us a screenshot of what that dialog looks like? In my VS, I have a list of installed templates on the left - and it says `Visual C#` at the top of that list - what does it say in your case? Also: each item in that dialog shows what language it will use in my case - and it's all showing C# - what does it show on your machine?

Comment: thats all dialog I'm getting...

Comment: Can you go to the `Solution Explorer` of your project, and right-click on the project (or a subfolder) and then pick `Add > New Item` from that context menu? Don't you get a much richer dialog with tons of options to pick from (and which shows what language you're currently picking for)

Comment: Yes, ok, that was selected as Visual Basic. So I added the new form and I'm going to continue now as usual, thank you! But why is it still defaulting to VB when I just go Add --> Web Form? It never did that. When I go to Add --> New Item then I can change the language now, and that is working, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `Add > New Item` dialog from the Object Explorer

[image]

in order to be able to pick what element you want to add (e.g. a webform), and in which language (C# vs. VB.NET).

[image]

Why it defaults to VB.NET when doing an `Add > New Form` - I don't know..... I didn't see any way to pick or define that on the project or solution level.....